# Join on If-else condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

- `T1 columns -> a, b, c , x
- `T2 columns -> d, e, f`

join is like this:

```
    if(a != NULL and a != c) 
     join condition is (a = f and b = d)
    else if(a == NULL or a == c)
     join condition is (c = f and x = e)
```

How to do this in sql?

Comment: This is a sign of messed up database design.

Answer (score 1):

Your database design is concerning, but for the sake of answering your question, you can just use `AND` and `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON (T1.a IS NOT NULL AND T1.a <> T1.c AND T1.a = T2.F AND T1.b = T2.d)
               OR (COALESCE(T1.a,T1.c) = T1.c AND T1.c = T2.f AND T1.x = T2.e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with union to accomplish this. Something like this might work.

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
       INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.a = t2.f AND t1.b = t2.d
WHERE T1.a != T1.c
  AND T1.a IS NOT NULL
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM T1
       INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.c = t2.f AND t1.b = t2.e
WHERE T1.a IS NULL
   OR T1.a = T1.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CASE`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM t1
            INNER JOIN t2
                       ON t2.f = CASE
                                   WHEN t1.a IS NOT NULL
                                        AND t1.a <> t1.c THEN
                                     t1.a
                                   ELSE
                                     t1.c
                                 END
                          AND CASE
                                WHEN t1.a IS NOT NULL
                                     AND t1.a <> t1.c THEN
                                  t2.d
                                ELSE
                                  t2.e
                              END = t1.b;
```

Comment: I request you to please modify your query as i have added x column in T1